# webm to mp3 conversion very slow with avconv

Tags: file-conversion, avconv, youtube-dl

I am using this

```
passthru("youtube-dl -o '../temp/%(title)s.%(ext)s' --restrict-
```

`filenames --no-part --no-progress --newline --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 -w --audio-quality 0 http://www.youtube.com$vid");`

as a part of my code where I download song from youtube-dl, but after downloading it takes 14-15 seconds to convert that to mp3. Is there any way to improve that and make the conversion faster ? Like make avconv use all cores. If so, then how ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
avconv -i File.webm -threads 2 -acodec libmp3lame -ab 128k -vn -f mp3 file.mp3
```

You can use 2 or more threads and change bitrate to improve speed of Your script.

Regards